# JPA native query with single column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need some help how to return just one column which is date as sample below. cuurently getting exception. is there to return java Date directly?

```
    Query currentAsOf = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT CURRENT_AS_OF FROM VW_OP_MKT_OFFERS",java.util.Date.class);
```

Will appreciate any help?

Answer (score 0):

You only use the createNativeQuery with a class to pass in an entity class that is to be built from the results.  If all you want is raw data, just pass in the SQL string to createNativeQuery and it will return the data as a list of Object[]:

```
Query currentAsOf = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT CURRENT_AS_OF FROM VW_OP_MKT_OFFERS");
List<Object[]> results = currentAsOf.getResultList();
```